# How to parse website protected with CloudFlare?

Tags: node.js, python-requests, puppeteer, cloudflare

My goal is to parse a website protected by CF. **I want to use requests** to get data, but all the time get **403** status code.

Is there a way to complete my task without using browser for every request? I'm good with opening browser once and then use default http requests

I've tried to use paid services, selenium, puppeteer and so on, but I don't want to use browser to do due to its memory loads.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.